# Automatic quitting of python file after a time period

Tags: python, timer, exit

Evening all,

I am working on a project to realise some form of cognitive radio.

I don't believe this to be a truly GNURadio question, rather a python one.

I have so far successfully enabled a spectrum scan and can set a local variable based on this for the optimum channel.  Additionally, I have been able to transmit that frequency (using a file) to the receiver for an over the air reconfiguration (OTAR).

What I am struggling with now, and hopefully it is a simple solution, Once I have sent the file for the OTAR I wish that python file generated by GNURadio to automatically close after a period, say 30 secs.  This should trigger the quitting rule, within this is the command to open my second transmission file which will send the data file.

Is there a simple way to get the GNURadio file to automatically quit after a given period?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# 
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

##################################################
#GNU Radio Python Flow Graph
# Title: Gmsk Tx
# Generated: Mon Jul 31 16:38:52 2017
#Edited for Project (import os and os.system("python ./Basic_SigGen.py") in def quitting():
#################################################



if __name__ == '__main__':

    import ctypes

    import sys

    if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):

        try:

            x11 = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libX11.so')

            x11.XInitThreads()

        except:

            print "Warning:failed to XInitThreads()"



from PyQt4 import Qt

from gnuradio import blocks

from gnuradio import digital

from gnuradio import eng_notation

from gnuradio import gr

from gnuradio import uhd

from gnuradio.eng_option import eng_option

from gnuradio.filter import firdes

from grc_gnuradio import blks2 as grc_blks2

from optparse import OptionParser

import sys

import time

import os




class GMSK_TX(gr.top_block, Qt.QWidget):


    def __init__(self):

    gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Gmsk Tx")

    Qt.QWidget.__init__(self)

    self.setWindowTitle("Gmsk Tx")

    try:

        self.setWindowIcon(Qt.QIcon.fromTheme('gnuradio-grc'))

    except:

        pass

    self.top_scroll_layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()

        self.setLayout(self.top_scroll_layout)

        self.top_scroll = Qt.QScrollArea()

        self.top_scroll.setFrameStyle(Qt.QFrame.NoFrame)

        self.top_scroll_layout.addWidget(self.top_scroll)

        self.top_scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.top_widget = Qt.QWidget()

        self.top_scroll.setWidget(self.top_widget)

        self.top_layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self.top_widget)

        self.top_grid_layout = Qt.QGridLayout()

        self.top_layout.addLayout(self.top_grid_layout)


        self.settings = Qt.QSettings("GNU Radio", "GMSK_TX")

        self.restoreGeometry(self.settings.value("geometry").toByteArray())



##################################################

# Variables

##################################################


    self.samp_rate = samp_rate = 1e6

        self.freq = freq = 2e9

    self.code1 = code1 = '010110011011101100010101011111101001001110001011010001101010001'



##################################################

# Blocks

##################################################


    self.uhd_usrp_sink_0_0 = uhd.usrp_sink(

            ",".join(("", "")),

            uhd.stream_args(

                cpu_format="fc32",

            channels=range(1),

        ),

    )

    self.uhd_usrp_sink_0_0.set_samp_rate(samp_rate)

    self.uhd_usrp_sink_0_0.set_center_freq(freq, 0)

    self.uhd_usrp_sink_0_0.set_gain(30, 0)

    self.uhd_usrp_sink_0_0.set_antenna('TX/RX', 0)

    self.digital_gmsk_mod_0 = digital.gmsk_mod(

        samples_per_symbol=2,

        bt=0.35,

        verbose=False,

        log=False,

    )

    self.blocks_multiply_const_vxx_0 = blocks.multiply_const_vcc((1, ))

    self.blocks_file_source_0 = blocks.file_source(gr.sizeof_char*1, '/root/optimum_freq.csv', False)

    self.blks2_packet_encoder_0 = grc_blks2.packet_mod_b(grc_blks2.packet_encoder(

                samples_per_symbol=2,

                bits_per_symbol=1,

            preamble='',

            access_code=code1,

            pad_for_usrp=True,

        ),

        payload_length=1,

    )



##################################################

# Connections

##################################################


    self.connect((self.blks2_packet_encoder_0, 0), (self.digital_gmsk_mod_0, 0))

    self.connect((self.blocks_file_source_0, 0), (self.blks2_packet_encoder_0, 0))

    self.connect((self.blocks_multiply_const_vxx_0, 0), (self.uhd_usrp_sink_0_0, 0))    

    self.connect((self.digital_gmsk_mod_0, 0), (self.blocks_multiply_const_vxx_0, 0))    



    def closeEvent(self, event):

        self.settings = Qt.QSettings("GNU Radio", "GMSK_TX")

        self.settings.setValue("geometry", self.saveGeometry())

        event.accept()



    def get_samp_rate(self):

        return self.samp_rate



    def set_samp_rate(self, samp_rate):

        self.samp_rate = samp_rate

        self.uhd_usrp_sink_0_0.set_samp_rate(self.samp_rate)



    def get_freq(self):

        return self.freq

    def set_freq(self, freq):

        self.freq = freq

        self.uhd_usrp_sink_0_0.set_center_freq(self.freq, 0)



    def get_code1(self):

        return self.code1



    def set_code1(self, code1):

        self.code1 = code1




def main(top_block_cls=GMSK_TX, options=None):


    from distutils.version import StrictVersion

    if StrictVersion(Qt.qVersion()) >= StrictVersion("4.5.0"):

        style = gr.prefs().get_string('qtgui', 'style', 'raster')

        Qt.QApplication.setGraphicsSystem(style)

    qapp = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)

    tb = top_block_cls()

    tb.start()

    tb.show()

    def quitting():

        tb.stop()

        tb.wait()

        os.system("python ./Basic_SigGen.py")

    qapp.connect(qapp, Qt.SIGNAL("aboutToQuit()"), quitting)

    qapp.exec_()




if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Comment: Please see how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

## You could use the python [sys](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) module...

To terminate a python script, you can call `sys.exit()`. I think this is what you want... And you can use the python [time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) module to create a timer as well. I can leave you to figure out how to do that or I can write I script that would go in a loop to check if the time has passed if you would rather.

Hope this helped!